# gradle build error while building apk ion ionic3 project

Tags: gradle, build, ionic3

Good day devloper pls i keep geting the eerror below while trying to build apk from my ionic3 project

Could not get unknown property 'cdvCompileSdkVersion' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

my build.gradle is below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    debugCompile project(path: ":CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: ":CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
}

    android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
    publishNonDefault true

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

    if (file('build-extras.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}
```

my package.json is below for further details if needed, i have tried to delete the build.gradle but it seems no to be helping

```
{
  "name": "Logistics",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-stepper": "^1.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.16",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not gradle problem, check if you are using plugins that have newer version of the current using cordova version.

Comment: how do i do that pls?

Comment: Update cordova and remove the build ,then do rebuild.

Comment: sorry o, how do i remove the build?, i dont mind if you can comment the  commands

Comment: ionic cordova platform rm android

Comment: //npm uninstall -g cordova
//npm install -g cordova

Comment: Then you add: ionic cordova build android

Comment: Thanks @Mostafa Harb, sorted

Comment: Welcome anytime bro <3.